# Is there a way to map complex json data onto interfaces in typescript while using observables?

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, google-news

I am trying to make simple web news reader, based mostly on google news api (https://newsapi.org/s/google-news-api). I have done everything like always so services, models etc. but i have problem with mapping my data onto concrete interfaces. Google api returns on one of the endpoint ('top-headlines') data in this format:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "totalResults": 38,
    "articles": [
       {
       "source": {
            "id": "the-new-york-times",
            "name": "The New York Times"
       },
      "author": null,
      "title": "Hong Kong Protesters Clash with Police Amid Fears of Mob 
       Violence - The New York Times",
      "description": "some description",
      "url": "https://www.nytimes.com/2019/08/11/world/asia/hong-kong- 
       protest.html",
      "urlToImage": 
      "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/08/11/world/11hongkong15/
       11hongkong15-facebookJumbo.jpg",
      "publishedAt": "2019-08-11T11:19:03Z",
      "content": "some content… [+751 chars]"
       },
      (...and many many more articles)
    ]
}
```

I need only articles. And i know that if i get this data from api like that i can call myvariablename.articles, but this does not seems right to me.

My attempt on first was to map in with rxjs map method. But i get error in console that there are is no property articles in Articles model. So I prepared response model and nested articles as property inside response model (interface). And i get exacly the same error. I was thinking that maybe there is some problem with defined in method Observable so i swiched to Response but with no luck, also right now i am getting error from my component where i am subscribing and using service method which says that: "Type Response[] is not assignable to type Article[]"

*top-news.service.ts*

```
(...all imports)

export class TopNewsService {

(... ommited defining of variables like url etc.)

  public getAll(): Observable<Response[]> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<Response[]>(`${this.url}/${this.endpoint}?country=us&apiKey=${this.token}`)
      .pipe(
        map(response => response.articles),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
(...error handling)
}
```

*article.ts*

```
export interface Article {
  source: {
    id: string;
    name: string;
  };
  author: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  url: string;
  urlToImage: string;
  publishedAt: string;
  content: string;
}
```

*response.ts*

```
import { Article } from './article';

export interface Response {
  status: string;
  totalResults: number;
  articles: Article;
}
```

*top-news-component.ts*

```
(...all imports)

export class TopNewsComponent implements OnInit {

  articles: Article[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private topNewsService: TopNewsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllProjects();
  }

  getAllProjects() {
    this.topNewsService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
      this.articles = data;
      console.log(this.articles)
    },
      (err: string) => {
        alert(err);
      });
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to map data inside service and return only articles and then (if this is possible) get this data inside my component and assign it to created variable with defined type Article[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using

```
this.httpClient.get<Response[]>
```

That means that you expect Google to return an array of Response. But that's not what it returns. It returns a **single** `Response`. So it should be

```
this.httpClient.get<Response>
```

And since you (try to) map this response to an array of articles, then the observable that your service returns is an `Observable<Article[]>`, not an `Observable<Response[]>`. So it should be

```
public getAll(): Observable<Article[]> {
```

This interface

```
export interface Response {
  status: string;
  totalResults: number;
  articles: Article;
}
```

is also wrong. A response doesn't contain a single article. It contains an array of article. Look at the JSON:

```
{
  "status": "ok", // one status string
  "totalResults": 38, // one totalResults number
  "articles": [ // an **array** of articles
    ..
  ]
}
```

So it should be

```
export interface Response {
  status: string;
  totalResults: number;
  articles: Article[];
}
```

Comment: damn, 2h of staring into code and i was puzzeled what was wrong. You are 100% right I am getting single response and expecting many and the interface implementation was wrong because i was expecting there one article. But one thing that was quite strange for me is the observable, because i was always thinking that i should use there like whole object that i get from the rest(read Response) not part of it that interests me and that i want to return from function.

Comment: either way i am marking this as a correct answer to my question and thank You for help

Comment: `this.httpClient.get<Response>(...)` is an Observable<Response>. But the whole point of the map() operator is to create another observable, emitting something different (a response mapped, or transformed, into something else). So the map() operator creates an Observable<Article[]> from an Observable<Response>.

Comment: ok now i get it. Because for me this was a part was working like charm but was also sounding a little bit odd. But this explanation has a lot of sense and makes all crystal clear. Once again thank You for your help